# Can a Swift statement be broken over multiple lines?

Tags: swift, syntax

The [language guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) says:

> Swift doesn’t require you to write a semicolon (;) after each statement in your code, although you can do so if you wish. However, semicolons are required if you want to write multiple separate statements on a single line.

This implies that Swift uses newlines as statement terminators. Does every statement need to fit on a single line? Or is it possible to insert a newline within a single statement - and if so, what are the rules that determine whether or not a newline terminates a statement?

Answer (score 2):

Swift can have newlines in statements. It is so common in complex commands like this:

```
 var query = HouseholdInfoTable.table
        .select(HouseholdInfoTable.uuid.distinct, HouseholdInfoTable.table[*])
        .join(PersonInfoTable.table, on: PersonInfoTable.householdUuid == HouseholdInfoTable.uuid)
        .filter(HouseholdInfoTable.houseNumber == houseNumber)
        .order(HouseholdInfoTable.sortName)
```

But you can have simple statements broken up, like this:

```
let a = 1
 + 2
let b = 1 +
2
```

Generally you can split the line across operands or punctuation

You can do multiline comments with line feeds in them like this:

```
let bigComment = """
anythingYou want can go here
asdlkasdkljfad
askjf
"""
```

Swift's style guide has more in-depth information:
https://google.github.io/swift/#line-wrapping

Playgrounds are a good place to see what the compiler handles.